# Unexpected search results - differences between normal search queries and content by search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, office-365

Did I miss a configuration option or is it a bug in the product?

**Situation:**

- We have multiple tenants - every environment has this problem
- It's query independant (weird search results, with multiple queries)
- It doesn't seem to be a language related issue (first sight)
- All actions below are performed by the Tenant admin

**Problem:**

We retrieve unexpected search results from the search result pages. In the search center, as well as in the default OSSSearchResult page.

The search result pages show less search results then the 'Content By Search' WebParts, with the same query.

We can search the individual items by searching on the "Title" managed property - with the exact title of the site. This means that they're indexed, but are not retrieved with other search queries who should match too.

**How to reproduce?**

- We setup a (Dutch) tenant
- We created 15 site collections within the Admin Center, with a TeamSite template.  They are all created in English. (You don't need to create that many site collections of course to reproduce)
- Wait couple hours to make sure that all site collections are indexed.
- Go to one of the site collections and enter the keyword "ContentClass:STS_Site" into the searchbox
- Are all the site collections, you've created before listed on the result page? Probably not.
- Place a Content By Search WebPart onto the page
- Configure the same query "ContentClass:STS_Site" in the webPart
- Notice that it displays all the site collections you've created

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Funny, I noticed this in a demo the other day and made a mental note to review when I had time. Thanks for asking and answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It had to do with the "TrimDuplicates" setting in the search results webpart. For more information...

http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-search-not-display-all-results/